# Using Glide for Android, how do I load images from asset and resources?

Tags: android, lazy-loading, android-glide

I want to keep all the transformation, stoke and animations identical and was thinking if we can pass resource ID or asset name in Glide to load it locally?

Answer (score 178, accepted):

For resource ids, you can use:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(R.drawable.resource_id)
    .into(imageView);
```

For assets, you can construct an asset uri:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/<assetName>"))
    .into(imageView);
```

Comment: for "assetName" do not forget to add the extension, ex: "image.jpg"

Comment: Shouldn't it be `R.drawable.resource_id`?

Comment: Might be obvious to others, but I spent a lot of time figuring this out because I thought `android_asset/assetName` should be replaced by my asset-path. Finally I found out it was only `assetName` and `file:///android_asset/` should always be present

Comment: Using with(fragment) is deprecated. Now you should use with(context)

Comment: Beware of `Uri.parse()` on modern android OS, instead go for `FileProvider.getUriForFile()`

Answer (score 7):

```
Glide
.with(context)
.load(uri)
.asBitmap()
.placeholder(R.drawable.yourimage)
.error(R.drawable.yourimage)
.into(yourview);
```

Apart from the above answer if the image URL return null you can load default image into the view as like above.

Answer (score 7):

It works when using `.asBitmap()`

```
String pathUri="file:///android_asset/img/flower.jpg";
Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(Uri.parse(pathUri)).into(holder.imgView_post);
```