# How to preserve listview in android when moving between multiple screens

Tags: android, android-intent

I have 3 screens **A**-landing page, **B**-listview Page, **C**-Detail page(Listview)

When i land on **A** and navigate to **B** it loads data and artifacts from memory in Async task which adds a bit of delay(this is acceptable since its my 1st load). When i click on specific member in the listview, go to **C** view and click back button, view **B** is preserved.
However if i click on back to go to view **A** and try to navigate to listview **B** it reloads again by calling oncreate. 
I have tried couple of approaches including `android:launchMode="singleTask"` 
, not setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` 
but could not get the desired result.

How can i prevent **B** from reloading when navigating from **A** in subsequent navigation.

Comment: You'll need to persist the data in your local database, after the first pull via async task. Then either set a shared preference variable with a boolean saying that data is cached recently or put timestamp in shared preference variable (which you can use to check how long ago was data cached & update accordingly). The main thing is to persist the fetched data, then set some sort of check either by checking for DB exists (or shared preference variable) & then moving to next activity. In case data is found in shared variable or DB, then your async task will load from memory again & send it to B.

Comment: I have sqlite DB from which im fetching data, since i have to re-render heavy items such as images that is adding up to considerable lag.

Comment: Look into RecyclerView, caching and lazy loading images ( http://androidahead.com/2017/01/28/lazy-loading-of-images/ & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982341/using-glide-for-android-how-do-i-load-images-from-asset-and-resources/29987915 ) for performance.